# Understanding “the mean minimizes the mean squared error”

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to understand the sentence

```
the mean minimizes the mean squared error.
```

from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation. 
From a previous post [Formal proof that mean minimize squared error function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967138/formal-proof-that-mean-minimize-squared-error-function) I can see a formal proof which according to the authors prove that the mean minimaze. But my objection on that prove is that is you substitute m with median all the reasoning still stands.

Therefore, I restricted myself to one dimension and built the following example :

```
MSE = 1/n[SUM(Y_hat_i - Y_i)**2]
```

Given the following distribution Y = [5,3,2,7,4], minimizing MSE I intended as in the following: I should find a function Y_hat such that when it is applied to the MSE formula (more specifically to each element of the Y distribution), we are sure that we obtain the minimum value. For simplicity, I could consider the Y_hat as any measure or function for the central tendency, including, mean, median, mode, etc.

Lets suppose, Y_hat = mean (=4.2 for our distribution), therefore, I did all the calculations such as:

```
1/5 [(4.2-5)**2 + (4.2-3)**2+ (4.2-2)**2 + (4.2-7)**2  + (4.2-4)**2 ] = 2.96
```

Let's suppose, Y_hat = median (=4 for our distribution), therefore, I did all the calculations such as:

```
1/5 [(4-5)**2 + (4-3)**2+ (4-2)**2 + (4-7)**2  + (4-4)**2 ] = 2.8
```

If I did all the calculation correctly, the result shows that for this case, the median is minimizing better than the mean.

I am sure, I am doing something wrong and missing important aspects of the overall reasoning.

Please, could you provide any clarification on the above topic? I would really appreciate it.

Many Thanks in advance, Best Regards, Carlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your calculation, we have
$$
\frac{(4-5)^2 + (4-3)^2+ (4-2)^2 + (4-7)^2  + (4-4)^2}{5} = \frac{15}{5} = 3 > 2.96.
$$
The mean minimizes the MSE indeed, no contradiction here.

Comment: Yes, you are right Martin. Thanks for the double check. My question is Why the mean is the function that minimizes the MSE?

Comment: I am looking at the prove given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967138/formal-proof-that-mean-minimize-squared-error-function but if I substitute m with median everything still work. What am I missing?

Comment: I am no statistician, but it is common in calculus for the absolute min value to occur at several different $x$s. Could the  same thing be happening here? Or, in your case, are the mean and median equal so there is no contradiction?

Comment: Thanks Randall. Problem solved by MartyCohen above.

Comment: @CarloAllocca I would say that the post of Reiner Martin matches more your question.

Comment: Thank you @Reiner Martin. Very good example. I like it a lot.

Answer (score 17):

If you have
$(y_i)_{i=1}^n$,
consider the
mean squared difference
from the $y_i$ 
to a value $a$.

This is
$s(a)
=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-a)^2
$.

Manipulating this,

$\begin{array}\\
s(a)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-a)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i^2-2ay_i+a^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^n2ay_i+\sum_{i=1}^na^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-2a\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+na^2\\
\end{array}
$

There are a number of ways
to minimize this expression.
Perhaps the easiest is
to differentiate
with respect to $a$.
This gives
$s'(a)
=-2\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+2na
$
and this is zero when
$a
=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n}
$,
the mean of the values.

Note that,
since 
$s''(a)
=2n > 0
$,
this value of $a$
gives a minimum.

---

(added later)

An even easier way is to write
$\bar{y}
=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n}
$
and
$\bar{y^2}
=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2}{n}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{n}s(a)
&=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-2a\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+a^2\\
&=a^2-2a\bar{y}+\bar{y^2}\\
&=a^2-2a\bar{y}+\bar{y}^2-\bar{y}^2+\bar{y^2}\\
&=(a-\bar{y})^2+\bar{y^2}-\bar{y}^2\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\bar{y^2}-\bar{y}^2$
is independent of $a$,
this is clearly a minimum when
$a = \bar{y}$
and the value
at the minimum is
$\bar{y^2}-\bar{y}^2$.

Comment: Many Thanks MartyCohen. This is what I was looking for. Your prove clearly shows that to min MSE, Y_hat MUST be the mean. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

More formally and generally we may state that expected value minimizes mean square error.

I.e. $c=\mathbb{E}(X)$ minimizes $\mathbb{E}((X-c)^2)$.

See two related cross-validated questions:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520286/how-can-i-prove-mathematically-that-the-mean-of-a-distribution-is-the-measure-th
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521433/how-to-prove-that-the-expected-value-minimizes-mean-square-error